# Finding files/folders with write/full control permissions for Everyone on Windows 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003, icacls

Trying to clean up permissions on this IIS6 w/ PHP CGI server, it seems that several files/folders have write permissions for Everyone. (You can probably guess what is happening, repeatedly.)

So, basically, I'm looking for the equivalent of `find $directory -perm 777 -exec ls -ld {} \;`

I can do that first part, *listing* files that *mention* Everyone with `icacls`, but can't seem to display the actual ACL:

`icacls \directory /findSID *S-1-1-0 /t`

Looking at the `subinacl` documentation and various google results, it seems that I can use /subdirectories and /display to achieve this, but it returns immediately with no results and no errors:

```
C:\>subinacl /subdirectories \directory\*.* /findsid=Everyone /display
+subdirectories \directory\*.*
/findsid=Everyone
/display

Elapsed Time: 00 00:00:00
Done:        0, Modified        0, Failed        0, Syntax errors        0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This worked for me with powershell and pstools:

`Get-ChildItem C:\temp\ -Recurse | Get-Acl | grep "Everyone"`

You may need to refine it more for your needs, but powershell is the way to go here.

Answer (score 6):

Orbitron's suggestion is great, but if you want to use a purely PowerShell way without having to install pstools, have a look at the `select-string` cmdlet. You may have to pipe the object pipeline to a file first and then consume it with select-string or you can wedge `out-string` into the pipeline.

`Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Get-Acl | out-string -stream | select-string -pattern "everyone"`

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: On my system when run in the root of C:\ drive at some point the command crashes with the following output -- `Get-Acl : Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation.
At line:1 char:26
+ Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Get-Acl | out-string -stream | select-string -pattern " ...
+                          ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-Acl], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.UnauthorizedAccessException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetAclCommand` -- Sorry for bad formatting I don't know how to make it better in a comment.